# Прибавить к url параметр "?"

Tags: html, javascript

Делаю сортировку продуктов на сайте. 
Повесил на тип сортировки ссылку типа:

```
<a href="/?sort=Price&direction=ASC">Возрастание цены</a>
```

Но мне необходимо, чтобы окончание ?sort=Price&direction=ASC" прибавлялась на любой странице сайта. А так,  он будет перебрасывать на главную. 
Сразу в голову пришла мысль через javascript прописать ссылке location.href, но в таком случае, если пользователь сперва нажмет на возрастание цены, потом еще на что-нибудь, то параметр ?sort=Price&direction=ASC будет плюсоваться к предыдущему параметру. 
Какое решение есть для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте немного изменить ваши ссылки

```
<a href="/?sort=Price&direction=ASC">Возрастание цены</a>
```

на

```
<a href="www.examle.com/price.php?sort=Price&direction=ASC">Возрастание цены</a>
```

В самом файле php

```
$sort= sanitizeString($_GET ['sort']);
$direction = sanitizeString($_GET ['direction']);
```

А эти переменные сохраните в Обьекте Класса (если используете ОП) или в глобальных перемнных которые можно подставлять в ссылки а можно и прозрачно использовать в запросах к БД и менять их явном указании в ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

все то же самое, но без /

Comment: не помогает

Comment: Значит либо у вас htaccess его режет, либо иной какой-то гет запрос. В таком случае вам придется пересобирать весь запрос

Comment: может регуляркой вырезать?